# Ipad in Landscape orientation does not apply autoresizingMask when you nav back to a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an ipad app(using NavigationViewController) that is in Landscape orientation. I can navigate down my view hierachary with no trouble and the screens appear ok. 
The table on the screen expands and use the correct proportions of the screen. When i hit the back button on the Nav bar and it goes back to the previous view the table's with seems to have gone back to the actual dimensions of the table when there is no

```
table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

applied.

This only happens when you navigate backwards. Is there some bug from the OS because I do not think I cause this.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply size changes in **viewWillAppear** too. Along with it reload the table.

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];


    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        [Table reloadData];
        // Set coordinates of views to have to change in landscape mode
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [Table reloadData];
        // Set coordinates of views to have to change in potrait mode

    }
```